# grunt.js - Multiple destinations when minifying files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

My grunt.js has a typical minification task:

```
min: {
    dist: {
        src: ['dist/precook.js'],
        dest: 'dist/precook.min.js'
    }
}
```

What is the simplest way to have multiple dest files? I'd like to minify into:

- dist/precook.min.js
- example/js/vendor/precook.min.js

The [built-in min task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_min.md) doesn't appear to support multiple destinations, so I assume this can be achieved via a simple "copy" task. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) plugin:

Install with [npm](https://npmjs.org/):

```
npm install grunt-contrib-copy
```

Modify `grunt.js` (add copy task definition and load copy plugin):

```
    ...
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'example/js/vendor/': 'dist/precook.min.js'
            }
        }
    }
    ...

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
```

Optionally [register `copy` in to grunt's default task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/grunt.task#grunt.task.registerTask).

The added beauty here is that you can now perform all other copy tasks as well. Even patterns are supported, like copy all minified files (`'dist/*.min.js'`).

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the extra trip on registering a default combined task!

Answer (score 7):

```
concat: {
            css: {
                src: ['UI.controls/assets/css/*.css'],
                dest: 'UI.controls/assets/css/min/production.css'
            },

            js: {
                src: ['UI.controls/assets/js/*.js'],
                dest: 'UI.controls/assets/js/min/production.js'
            },

            js2: {
                src: ['UI.core/assets/js/*.js'],
                dest: 'UI.core/assets/js/min/production.js'
            }

        },

        cssmin: {
            css: {
                src: 'UI.controls/assets/css/min/production.css',
                dest: 'UI.controls/assets/css/min/production.min.css'
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            js: {
                src: 'UI.controls/assets/js/min/production.js',
                dest: 'UI.controls/assets/js/min/production.min.js'
            },

            js2: {
                src: 'UI.core/assets/js/min/production.js',
                dest: 'UI.core/assets/js/min/production.min.js'
            }
        },


        watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['UI.controls/assets/css/*.css'],
                tasks: ['concat:css', 'cssmin:css']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['UI.controls/assets/js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['concat:js', 'uglify:js']
            },

            js2: {
                files: ['UI.core/assets/js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['concat:js', 'uglify:js']
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative approach (next to **@jalonen**'s solution) which may to interesting to you, IF you are using [**requirejs**](http://requirejs.org/) to modularize your project, then you can use the [requirejs optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to minify your modules.

First of all, you need to add [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) to your project:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-requirejs --save-dev
```

**Grunt configuration:**

```
        requirejs: {
            production:{
                options:{
                    // don't include libaries when concatenating/minifying
                    paths:{
                        angular:'empty:',
                        jquery:'empty:'
                    },
                    baseUrl:'path/to/src/js',
                    dir:'path/to/target/js',
                    // keeps only the combined files
                    removeCombined:true,
                    modules:[
                        {name:'app', exclude: ['moduleA', 'moduleB']},
                        {name:'moduleA'},
                        {name:'moduleB'}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        ...

     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
```

**Explanation:**

Let's say you have this dependency tree (`->` means *depends on*):

```
app -> moduleA -> moduleA1
               -> moduleA2              
app -> moduleB -> moduleB1
               -> moduleB2
```

After minifying you will have three files:

- `app` (minified version of app)
- `moduleA` (minified version of `moduleA`, `moduleA1`, and `moduleA2`)
- `moduleB` (minified version of `moduleB`, `moduleB1`, and `moduleB2`)

Comment: Thanks @asgoth. I've more grunt (0.4~) experience since the original question and I'm now using `grunt-contrib-requirejs` in a similar way to this.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and created a [grunt multi-task](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-multi-dest) that runs a list of specified tasks on multiple directories

Usage for the exact case:
```

```
min: {
    dist: {
        src: ['dist/precook.js'],
        dest: 'dist/precook.min.js'
    }
},
multidest: {
    minifiedFiles: {
        tasks: ['min'],
        dest: [
            'dist/precook.min.js',
            'example/js/vendor/precook.min.js'
       ]
    }
}
```

```